# What is the Inverse function in topological spaces?

Tags: general-topology, functions

If The usual topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}$ and $X=\{a,b,c,d\}$ with the topology $\rho=\{\phi,X,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\},\{a,b,c\}\}$. Then the function $f:(\mathbb{R},\tau)\longrightarrow (X,\rho)$ defined by
\begin{equation*}
 f(x) = \begin{cases}
  c, & if \quad x \in \mathbb{Q} \\
  a, &if \quad x \in \mathbb{I}_{rr}
 \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
I know the $f^{-1}(\{a\})=\mathbb{I}_{rr}$ and $f^{-1}(\{c\})=\mathbb{Q}$. But, I'm not sure about $f^{-1}(\{b\})=\phi$ or not?

Comment: $f^{-1}(A)$ is not the inverse function but the inverse image, or pre-image.

Comment: It is empty, for $f^{-1}(\{b\})$ is the set of all real numbers $x$ such that $f(x) = b$.

Comment: ok, i got it thank you for your answer.